# Passing variable through URL with angular js

Tags: angularjs, infinite-loop, infinite-scroll, infinite

I am using angular to make an e-commerce, and I'm setting an infinite scroll to the products list page. Everything worked fine, but I want to use the URL to set the page, so the user can access an specific page through URL. how do I set a variable like "pageNumber" in the URL with angular? like "www.page.com/page/2/"(I want to get the number 2 and pass it to the store controller)

Here's the code I have now

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('concurseirosUnidos', ['store-directives', 'ngRoute']);
    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/products-list.html'})
    .when("/page/$pageNumber"), {
        // probably I'd need to put something here?
    })
     .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});;
    }
});

  app.controller('StoreController', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope){
    var store = this;
    store.products = [];      

    $http.get('/app/products/products.json').success(function(data){
        store.products = data;
    });

    if(typeof page === 'undefined'){
        var page = 1;   
    }else{
      //if it's defined through the url, page = pageNumberFromURL
    }
    $scope.myLimit = 3 * page;

    $scope.nextPage = function () {
        page++; // I want this function to actually update the url and get the variable from there
        $scope.myLimit = 3 * page;
    };

  }]);

})();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You use `$routeParams` to get the values of a specific named group in a `$route` definition.

[**REFERENCE**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

**Example:**

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/page/:page_number', {
    // your route details
  });
})

.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  console.log($routeParams.page_number); // prints the page number
});
```

In relation to your code, it should look something like this:

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('concurseirosUnidos', ['store-directives', 'ngRoute']);
    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/products-list.html'})
    .when("/page/:page_number"), {
        templateUrl: 'partials/page.html', // I made this up
        controller: 'StoreController'
    })
     .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});;
    }
});

  app.controller('StoreController', ['$http', '$scope', '$routeParams', function($http, $scope, $routeParams){
    var store = this;
    var page = $routeParams.page_number;
    store.products = [];      

    $http.get('/app/products/products.json').success(function(data){
        store.products = data;
    });

    if(typeof page === 'undefined'){
        var page = 1;   
    }else{
      // if $routeParams.page_number is defined to you implementation here!
    }

    $scope.myLimit = 3 * page;

    $scope.nextPage = function () {
        page++; // I want this function to actually update the url and get the variable from there
        $scope.myLimit = 3 * page;
    };

  }]);

})();
```

Comment: Sure =D, I was just checking if I had no more questions...thank you again