# How to send data from one View to another View in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-router

Could you please tell me how to send data from one view to another using state. I don't want to use factory or service. I need to send the data using url and get the data from url and display it on view.
I have one field `name` in my first View. I want to display on the second view whatever user enters in the input field. On button click, I need to send it to another view. I am able to go to the next view but how to send the data?

Plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/iDlzhzkz0pJKN2f2CZZe?p=preview

```
var loginCntrl = function($scope, $location, $state) {
  $scope.testClick = function() {
    $state.go("navigation2");
  }

  $scope.name = "";

  /*$scope.fullname = function() {
    return $scope.firstname + $scope.lastname;
  };*/
}
```

Comment: Before you will get your answer, this should give you some idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27699798/1679310

Comment: Check it here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609747/passing-variable-through-url-with-angular-js

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/iDlzhzkz0pJKN2f2CZZe?p=preview I try link that but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$state.go can have a parameters object to pass on to the view

Check here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options

```
$state.go("State", {Hello:"Hi!"});
```

You can then pick up those params on the view controller using $stateParams

```
app.controller("SomeController", function($scope, $stateParams){
    $scope.NewHello = $stateParams.Hello;
})
```

You will also need to amend the URL to accept this parameter:

```
url:"/someurl/{Hello}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that you will need to provide the state params in the URL parameter. In this case "/no/{Hello}". I've amended your Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/GVrYtoBNBKb7xjQioQke?p=preview

Comment: Thanks It works ..If I need to send two parameter how i will send like "world" also

Comment: could you please tell me how I will send multiple parameters

Comment: Add it on to the end of the URL property and use it as you would any other state param. In this case "/No/{Hello}{World}".  Here you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/cIZtDlghzAyAahxzcIdy?p=preview